# retrieving an object from boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

Suppose a method returns something like this

```
boost::optional<SomeClass> SomeMethod()
{...}
```

Now suppose I have something like this

```
boost::optional<SomeClass> val = SomeMethod();
```

Now my question is how can I extract SomeClass out of val ?

So that I could do something like this:

```
SomeClass sc = val ?
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use the de-reference operator:

```
SomeClass sc = *val;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `get()` method:

```
SomeClass sc = val.get();
```

Both of these return an lvalue reference to the underlying `SomeClass` object.

Answer (score 11):

To check if the optional contains a value, and the optionally retrieve it:

```
boost::optional<SomeClass> x = SomeMethod();
if (x)
     x.get();
```

To get the optional value, or a default value if it does not exist:

```
SomeMethod().get_value_or(/*default value*/)
```

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in the previous answers, the de-reference operator and the function `get()` have the same functionality. Both require the optional to contain valid data.

```
if (val)
{
    // the optional must be valid before it can be accessed
    SomeClass sc1 = *val;
    SomeClass sc2 = val.get();
}
```

An alternative is the function `value()`, which throws an exception if the optional does not carry a value.

```
// throws if val is invalid
SomeClass sc3 = val.value();
```

Alternatively, the functions `value_or` and `value_or_eval` can be used to specify defaults that are returned in case the value is not set.